# How to See the Application logs in Pod

Tags: kubernetes

We are moving towards Microservice and using K8S for cluster orchestration. We are building infra using Dynatrace and Prometheus server for metrics collection but they are yet NOT in good shape.
Our Java Application on one of the Pod is not working. I want to see the application logs.

How do I access these logs?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the application logs to stdout/err, `kubectl logs -n namespacename podname`.

Comment: @dotnetavalanche App logs are redirected to pod logs

Comment: Pod logs are the stdout and stderr from the container processes. If your app logs to something else then you would need to reconfigure it to be pointed at stdout and/or stderr.